# Replace word tag to entire file content

Tags: sed

Assume that we have a content xml-file:

```
<field name="id" id="1" type="number" default="" />
```

Assume that we have template file with tag:

```
INCLUDE_XML
```

We need to replace `INCLUDE_XML` tag to entire content from xml-file. We can try.

```
tpl_content=$(<tpl.xml)
xml_content=$(<cnt.xml)
xml_content="$(echo "$tpl_content" | sed "s/INCLUDE_XML/"$xml_content"/g")"
echo "$xml_content" > out.xml
```

The problem is `unterminated 's' command` cause xml-file has lot of bless characters (quotes, slashes, etc). How we can do the replacement without this care about the characters in content xml-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `sed`'s built-in facilities.

```
sed -e '/INCLUDE_XML/!b' -e 'r cnt.xml' -ed tpl.xml >out.xml
```

Translation: if the current input line doesn't match the regex, just continue. Otherwise, read in and print the other file, and delete the current line.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Especially for the translation of the magic.